# WCF service with JSONP over SSL

Tags: json, ssl, wcf, jsonp

We have a SSL configured website that hosts a WCF-service. The service's binding has `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"` and communication is serialized using JSON.

When we request this service from http it returns JSONP but when it is requested using HTTPS it returns just JSON. I need to have JSONP in either way, please help.

Current configuration is like this:

```
<webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
</webHttpBinding>

<behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="JsonServiceBehaviors">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors><behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior></endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
            <service name="Backend.CIService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonServiceBehaviors">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
                          bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="Backend.ICIService"
                          behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
            </service></services>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What happens if you use this configuration:

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="jsonp" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  <binding name="jsonpSsl" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
    <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JsonServiceBehaviors">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="Backend.CIService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonServiceBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="jsonp" contract="Backend.ICIService"
      behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="jsonpSsl" contract="Backend.ICIService"
      behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

The problem is that if you want to call service over both HTTP and HTTPS you must provide two endpoints - one for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

Comment: I've never been able to get http and https working at the same time before, even with multiple endpoints. I'm not sure what exactly I was doing wrong, but this is the least confusing (and most successful) wcf answer I've seen. In fact it makes sense :) Not only that, it's made my need for cross domain scripts redundant! Woohoo! :D

Comment: For those new to WCF... the <webHttpBinding> element needs to go inside a <bindings> element.

Comment: Ditto @Radderz - I dont understand why the internet is full of examples that are hard to follow.  No idea why THIS example worked, where 20 other's didnt (and no doubt because I was doing something wrong), but I finally have my WCF service responding over http and https, and is RESTful as well to boot!