# WCF JSON SSL configuration

Tags: .net, wcf, json, ssl

I have a WCF server returning JSON working fine.
Until I access the page via SSL  (Certificate is installed)
I have the following configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Analytics">
    <endpoint name="jsonEP"
            address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="json"
            contract="IAnalytics"/>     
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="json">
      <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="true" />      
    </behavior>     
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**What do I need to change to enable my service to be SSL enabled?**

I access the entry page with https://mysite/Service/Analytics.svc
but the message gives
svcutil.exe http://**machinename**/Service/Analytics.svc?wsdl

when it should be http://**mysite**/Service/Analytics.svc?wsdl

Also any Get Requests fail
ex:
http://mysite/Service/Analytics.svc/MyURITemplate/Id/1

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a binding element and set the security to *transport*.

Have a look at a sample [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx).

Comment: It was close. but this is what worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192132/wcf-service-with-jsonp-over-ssl

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I had to turn off IIS SSL Setting to Require SSL and follow this configuration.
[WCF service with JSONP over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192132/wcf-service-with-jsonp-over-ssl)

I still get the wrong URL in the Analytics.svc "homepage"

"svcutil.exe http://machinename/Service/Analytics.svc?wsdl "