# How do I bind WCF json to https with multiple bindings?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am using WCF to bind webservices to SOAP and JSON.  I must run ssl in production.  I've bound the soap address to https, but I cannot figure out how to bind the JSON address to https.   Here is my config.

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="EnterpriseServices.Service.AuthorizationServiceBase">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EnterpriseServices.Contracts.Authorization.IAuthorizationManagerBase" />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="EnterpriseServices.Contracts.Authorization.IAuthorizationManagerBase" />
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="EnterpriseServices.Contracts.Authorization.IAuthorizationManagerBase" />
  </service>
...
```

Is there a protocolMapping I can add for my "json" endpoint that I can use to bind to https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the security mode set to Transport in your bindings?

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="jsonpSsl">
     <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Check out this answer: [WCF service with JSONP over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192132/wcf-service-with-jsonp-over-ssl)

Comment: I had to add that binding configuration and a non-ssl binding to the endpoint then it worked.